# SDN: How to map a collection of nodes to a @NodeEntity class member?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a graph that includes:

(User)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(Group)

(User)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(Managers)-[:MANAGES]->(Group)

In the application I have the class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class UserEntity {
  @Property
  private Long id;

  @Relationship(type = "MEMBER_OF", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
  private List<GroupEntity> memberInGroups;

  private List<GroupEntity> managesGroups;
}
```

In the repository I have a method to get a User like so:

```
@Query("match (u:User{id:{id}) " +
        "optional match (u)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group) " +
        "optional match (u)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(s:Managers)-[:MANAGES]->(m:Group) " +
        "return u,collect(g) as memberInGroups,collect(m) as managesGroups")
Optional<UserEntity> findById(Long id);
```

The problem is that this query returns the result correctly in the browser, meaning I have some values (not null) for memberInGroups *and* for managesGroups.

However, when I make the call via the application I get the memberInGroups filled in as expected but managesGroups is null.

I assume this is a mapping issue, since managesGroups doesn't have a Relationship annotation nor a Property annotation.

Is there a way to get the managesGroups value to show up correctly inside the UserEntity object?

Answer (score 0):

You can only map the same relationship type within one class to different target types/classes ([docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:relationship:type-discrimination)). Of course you would still need the annotation on the other relationship definition.

In your concrete case there is another problem: You cannot "skip" relationships/nodes in the graph and just let it get mapped to the entity.
A solution to achieve this would be to also model the `Managers` and within this class the `Group` relationship. Then it would be mandatory to also name and return the relationships in your custom query.